# How to remove everything after certain pattern in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got variables such  as hotel tag (8) and yoga tag (4)

Is it possible to get values as **hotel tag** and **yoga tag**

```
var myarray = ["hotel tag (8)", "yoga tag (4)"];
var newarray = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
        var tag_name = myarray[i].split('(').pop()
        newarray.push(tag_name);
    }
    console.log(newarray); 
});
```

I have tried to use `split` and `pop`, but I am getting incorrect results.

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/303/

Comment: Where are the variables coming from? Can you not amend their values at source?

Answer (score 1):

Your were close.

Actually [Array.prototype.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last element from an array and returns that element. So you were storing this last element inside your `tag_name` and adding it to the `newarray`

```js
var myarray = ["hotel tag (8)", "yoga tag (4)"];
var newarray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    var tag_name = myarray[i].split('(')[0].trim();
    newarray.push(tag_name);
}
console.log(newarray);
```

**OR**

If you want to keep the same logic. You can use [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/shift) that will remove the first element from an array and will return that element.

```js
var myarray = ["hotel tag (8)", "yoga tag (4)"];
var newarray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    var tag_name = myarray[i].split('(').shift().trim();
    newarray.push(tag_name);
}
console.log(newarray);
```

*Note : I added the method `trim()` to remove leading and ending white space*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression and search for first non open bracked parts.

```js
var myarray = ["hotel tag (8)", "yoga tag (4)"];
myarray.forEach(function (a) {
    console.log(a.match(/^[^(]+/)[0].trim());
});
```

Or use a positive lookahead with match

```js
var myarray = ["hotel tag (8)", "yoga tag (4)"];
myarray.forEach(function (a) {
    console.log(a.match(/^.*(?=\s\()/)[0]);
});
```

Or use a positive lookahead with split

```js
var myarray = ["hotel tag (8)", "yoga tag (4)"];
myarray.forEach(function (a) {
    console.log(a.split(/(?=\s\()/)[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There ya go:

```js
var data = ["hotel tag (8)", "yoga tag (4)"];

var result = data.map(function(str){
  return str.split('(')[0].trim();
});

console.log(result);
```

It doesn't get any simpler than this.

For each element:

1. split it at `(` with `.split('(')`,
2. get the first part (`[0]`),
3. remove trailing spaces with `.trim()`.